# moving files to subdirectory in linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to figure out how to:

move the contents of

```
/var/www/html/1/ to /var/www/html/
```

in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mv -i /var/www/html/1/* /var/www/html
```

The `-i` is there for safety; it will ask confirmation before overwriting an existing file.